# Declare a variable based on Type returned by GetType

Tags: c#, casting, json.net

My Query is both related to the following situation which is specific to JValue of newtonsoft as well as normal scenario in C# environment.

I have a JObject and I extract the property "version" from this JObject. I then try to extract the value of the property version. 
At this stage I don't know what datatype it is (int or long or string or double).

```
JObject jObj = myObject as JObject;
JProperty jprop = jObj.Properties().ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "version");
JValue version = jprop.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(jprop, null) as JValue;
```

I need to compare this value of version currently in Jvalue to another variable let's say long myVersionValue , so I need to basically cast this and do the comparison, following works for me fine. Since I know that I have to compare to long I try to cast it first and then compare.

```
if(myVersionValue == (long)version.Value))
```

But let's say that I want to do make this casting generic, where I extract the Type of myVersionValue and then apply the casting . I tried below

```
if(myVersionValue == (myVersionValue.GetType())version.Value
```

But it throws exceptions and I could not figure out how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My query is basically focused on how to declare a variable based on Type returned by GetType() . I can't mention Long or Int in my code , i need this to be resolved through GetType() , as such , the other question partially answers my query. I more curious on finding the syntax for declaring a variable based on Type returned by GetType(). e.g. given the scenario in the problem statement, if i need to declare a variable as `myVersionValue.GetType() variable = (myVersionValue.GetType())version.Value` something like this , is there any syntax in C#

Comment: The answer is that you can't. Sorry.